# What are miscellaneous targets in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

What does it mean by miscellaneous targets? Are they in any way different from the normal targets we set?

I read them in the below link I have shared.

"Examples of weak references in Cocoa include, but are not restricted to, table data sources, outline view items, notification observers, and miscellaneous targets and delegates."

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html

Comment: I think miscellaneous here means "various". Somebody back me up?

Comment: I believe the docs refer to the "usual" targets; they wanted to avoid listing the many views that employ the target/action mechanism.

Comment: There is no special kind as miscellaneous targets AFAIK.. I think the documentation is side stepping to reference all views in single step..